# Skipping error files when downloading using download.file in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, download

I have a larger number of links to pdf files that I would like to download using download.file in a for loop. My solution works fine, but it stops when it encounters an error (a number of the files does not work). I would like to add a feature to my download.file function that tells R to skip a file if downloaded yields an error and to print a message with the names of the pages for which an error was encountered.

I found that tryCatch is likely a good solution in this case, but I am not entirely sure where to place it (I have tried a number of ways, but neither worked).

Here is my code:

```
for (i in length(files) {

# Reads the html links 
  html <- read_html(files[i])
  reads_name <- html_nodes(html, 'h1') 
  name <- trimws(html_text(reads_name) )

# Extracts the pdf. link from all links that the webpage contains 
  webpagelinks <- html_attr(html_nodes(html, "a"), "href")
  extract_pdf_link <- webpagelinks[grepl("\\pdf", webpagelinks)]

# downloads the pdf file from the pdf link, here is where I get the error 
  download.file(extract_pdf_link, destfile = paste0(name, "_paper.pdf") , 
mode = "wb")

  skip_with_message = simpleError('Did not work out')
  tryCatch(print(name), error = function(e) skip_with_message)

  }
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put `download.file` inside `tryCatch`. For example

```
files <- c("http://foo.com/bar.pdf", "http://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf", "http://bar.com/foo.pdf")
oldw <- getOption("warn")
options(warn = -1)
for (file in files) {
    tryCatch(download.file(file, tempfile(), mode = "wb", quiet = FALSE), 
        error = function(e) print(paste(file, 'did not work out')))    
}
options(warn = oldw)
```

I turn warnings off at the start using `options(warn = -1)` to suppress extraneous warning messages, and restore the previous settings at the end.  This will give you an output like

```
# trying URL 'http://foo.com/bar.pdf'
# [1] "http://foo.com/bar.pdf did not work out"
# trying URL 'http://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf'
# Content type 'application/pdf' length 20597 bytes (20 KB)
# ==================================================
# downloaded 20 KB

# trying URL 'http://bar.com/foo.pdf'
# [1] "http://bar.com/foo.pdf did not work out"
```