# Error when downloading multiple pdf files from list of urls in R

Tags: r, pdf, web-scraping

I have a list of urls and trying to download the pdfs they link to with lapply. Even though the download bar pops up, I get the following message and the files are not downloaded:

only first element of 'destfile' argument usedtrying URL 'https://reliefweb.int/sites/reliefweb.int/files/resources/hno_car_2021_final_fr.pdf'
Content type 'application/pdf' length 22087482 bytes (21.1 MB)
downloaded 21.1 MB

```
names<- lapply(pdf, basename) # get names
destination<- paste0 ("~/", names)
lapply(pdf,download.file, destfile=destination)
```

```
pdf
[[1]]
[1] "https://reliefweb.int/sites/reliefweb.int/files/resources/hno_car_2021_final_fr.pdf"

[[2]]
[1] "https://reliefweb.int/sites/reliefweb.int/files/resources/rnro_centralsahel_oct_2020_fr_web.pdf"

[[3]]
[1] "https://reliefweb.int/sites/reliefweb.int/files/resources/rnro_centralsahel_oct_2020_en_web.pdf"

[[4]]
[1] "https://reliefweb.int/sites/reliefweb.int/files/resources/hno_2020-final.pdf"

[[5]]
[1] "https://reliefweb.int/sites/reliefweb.int/files/resources/hno_light_2020-en_final_0.pdf"

[[6]]
[1] "https://reliefweb.int/sites/reliefweb.int/files/resources/20200701_HNO_CENTROAMERICA%20ADDENDUM%20ING.pdf"

[[7]]
[1] "https://reliefweb.int/sites/reliefweb.int/files/resources/20200706%20ONEPAGER%20HNO%20Centroame%CC%81rica%20ING.pdf"

[[8]]
[1] "https://reliefweb.int/sites/reliefweb.int/files/resources/cmr_hno_2020-revised_print.pdf"

[[9]]
[1] "https://reliefweb.int/sites/reliefweb.int/files/resources/20200616_HNO_CENTROAMERICA%20ADDENDUM.pdf"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would handle everything at once. see code example for the first 2 files.

```
names = c("https://reliefweb.int/sites/reliefweb.int/files/resources/hno_car_2021_final_fr.pdf",
          "https://reliefweb.int/sites/reliefweb.int/files/resources/rnro_centralsahel_oct_2020_fr_web.pdf"
)


# making the filenames
downloaded = lapply(names, function(url){
  # extract the last part of the url to make the filename
  destination = unlist(strsplit(url, '/'))
  destination = destination[length(destination)]
  destination = paste0 ("~/", destination)
  # download the file
  download.file(url = url, destfile=destination, mode="wb")
  return(destination) # This is optional, just the see where the files are saved
})

# downloaded

# [[1]]
# [1] "~/hno_car_2021_final_fr.pdf"

# [[2]]
# [1] "~/rnro_centralsahel_oct_2020_fr_web.pdf"
```

Comment: Thank you! I managed to download the files, but any idea why it does not save the documents in the working directory? and can I do anything so they are saved there?

Comment: Another issue I had also is that the code would stop everytime a link failed (in my actual data I have 230 links and some of them may no longer work) I removed the ones that did not work with subsetting the inital list but is there a way to automate this as part of the function?

Comment: if you want to save the files to your working directory, you need to specify it explicitly: ```destination = paste0 (getwd(), '/', destination)```. Note that the ```~``` (in ```paste0 ("~/", destination)```) means home instead of working directory.

Comment: For the files that do not get downloaded see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50624864/skipping-error-files-when-downloading-using-download-file-in-r. You may also be interested in `download_retry` function from `recount` package  (https://rdrr.io/bioc/recount/man/download_retry.html) which allow you to retry failed downloads, since the task can fail for various reasons (e.g. internet connection issues).